# Properly secured soffit?

Tags: repair, framing, roof, attic, soffit

I noticed a sizeable gap between the facia board and the truss supports in my attic.

- Length of the overhang is 22ft long. It has a 40in overhang.
- only about 1/3rd of the rafters have nails extending out to the facia board.
- the soffit is framed out, but the 2x4s don't line up with the rafters, so none of the soffit framing 2x4s are connected to the rafters.
- beneath the soffit 2x4s is plywood, which seems to take away the ability of the soffit vents from being able to vent air into the attic
- the soffit appears level, and I have been the homeowner for over 6 years (the soffit work was done prior to my occupation)

  **Am I correct in thinking that there is something wrong with this? If so, how do I go about correcting it?**

[image: Inside]
[image: Outside]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to agree that the construction of that soffit is rather questionable. You will need to ask yourself if it OK as is because it has been hanging there for 6+ years. Trying to do something with the soffit framing and work out some way to secure it to the rafter tails would be a huge job as it entails opening up the whole bottom side and even some of the adjacent house siding may need to be removed.

There is a good possibility that the house was re-sided at some more recent time *(the picture shows as a pretty decent looking structure)*. At that time the soffit covering was probably added under the bottom of that plywood without the installers having any clue with regard to venting. In fact it even seems that the original plywood did not even have cutouts in it for venting.

You could go about taking off some of that soffit covering and then providing some holes in the plywood that match up with some of the soffit cover venting. That will be a big project to do that though because it seems it may even involve taking down the rain gutter in the process.

There may be an alternative method to provide venting by using a proper sized hole saw and making round holes through both the soffit cover and the plywood. Then install round vents similar to these:

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://ventmastersstore.com/products/1-round-plastic-vent-white?variant=5129825988&currency=USD&gclid=Cj0KCQjw17n1BRDEARIsAFDHFewp6xOLFS_Bx6mjtNveoQwExa8-2_v39DVupxGLZvF6sTisOj0-q5MaAnNtEALw_wcB)*</sup>

You can find these in various sizes like 1", 2.5" diameter. The one above is plastic but you can also find metal ones made of aluminum. Most fit into the hole by friction fit although I've seen some of the aluminum type stapled to the soffit through the narrow outer lip.

As you go about investigating soffit vents you will also have to take a look at what vents out the rafter area near the roof peak. Your pictures do not provide an indication if there is such venting.